# Como tirar o Botão de Opções lateral do JInternalFrame

Tags: java

Olá, desejo retirar esse botão de opções lateral do meu JInternalFrame: [image: print da tela]

Após ler em alguns lugares, vi que teoricamente esse comando funcionária para retirar o botão:

```java
((BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
```

Quando tento usar este, me aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Main.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
          ^
  symbol:   class BasicInternalFrameUI
  location: class Window
1 erro
```

Segue, meu código:

```java
class Window extends JInternalFrame{
    Window(String name,  int id){
        [...]
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);

        [...]
    }
    public void setPosition() {
        [...]
        }
    }

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que possamos ver o problema de uma forma mais ampla, é essencial testar, porém, seu código, como é apenas um fragmento, não permite isso. Se possivel, forneça uma versao reduzida do seu codigo, que seja possivel executar somente o problema pra que a gente possa te ajudar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar isso no construtor da classe.

```
setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
BasicInternalFrameUI bi = (BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI();
bi.setNorthPane(null);
```

Isso remove o menu de opções, mas também a borda.
Você pode fazer um botão de fechar e minimizar personalizado também, caso queira manter, mas ai vai do gosto.